# when I press the button rotates the screen

Tags: android, screen

I want to code the following
When I press the button rotates the screen and when Adgd the back button closes the screen rotation please, and thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this code may help you :

```
Button buttonSetPortrait = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setPortrait);
Button buttonSetLandscape = (Button)findViewById(R.id.setLandscape);

buttonSetPortrait.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
   }

});

buttonSetLandscape.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
   }

});
```